# 404 Missing jQuery in _layouts folder

Tags: javascript, csom, jsom

I have been stuck for a while trying to find out what exactly the _layouts folder does for SharePoint and why it may be causing any script I write and attempt to deploy on the site to not work.  They are simple scripts attempting to gain access to the CSOM to be able to manipulate list data.  I use the following source references at the top of my code:

```
   <script 
src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" 
type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script
type="text/javascript"
src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">
</script>
```

The error when the page loads: `HTTP404: NOT FOUND GET - https://urimdev.byu.edu/_layouts/15/RecordsManagement/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.map`

With my limited knowledge of this framework, I suspect that this may be causing the problem the following error (the one where the script stops working)`:

```
Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference MicrosoftAjax.js
```

Can anyone with SharePoint development experience help me understand these errors so I can get my scripts working in my site collection?

Comment: Looks like you don't have the right jquery  file uploaded.  1.7.2.min vs 1.10.2.min.map

Answer (score 0):

`_layouts` is a virtual directory that maps to a folder in the file system of a SharePoint server. This folder is used to store files and templates (including JavaScript files) that are used across the SharePoint farm.

I cover how to deploy and reference JavaScript files in my [JavaScript and jQuery for SharePoint Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbE9ytxabzs) conference session which I've recorded and uploaded to YouTube.

Seeing that you are new to SharePoint development, you may also find [SharePoint 2010 for ASP.NET Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=an1IkFzHpBk) valuable. It was recorded for SharePoint 2010 but most of the material applies to SharePoint 2013.